# DVD Playback in C#?

Tags: c#, playback, dvd

I am in need of a component or control that can read a DVD and play it back either on the current window, on another window, or in an arbitrary position on-screen (to be indicated programmatically).  There do not need to be any user-visible controls on it; the app will handle that separately.  Where do I need to turn?

FYI, I'm using .Net 3.5 in a winforms application.

I feel like I'm probably missing something simple, but it is escaping me. ;-)

-- afward

Comment: This cannot be done in Windows 8 without paying for the proper codecs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Windows Media Player control.  The example is in VB.NET, but you should be able to translate very easily.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562852(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Just noticed that the C# version of that article is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562851(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Embed the windows media control to your window.
Here is the c# code :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562851(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Would you mind bringing some of that code into your answer? If the link changes and 404's in the future, this won't help anyone. Can you summarize it?

Answer (score 0):

Using an embedded media player control is a very good idea.

you might also wanna take a look at:
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3215&lngWId=10