# Load encrypt media file from dvd on player without copy on hard disk in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I encrypted video file (encrypted file on Dvd). How can I decrypt file and display in media player without copy file(decrypted file) in disk(Hard drives)?(c# & winforms)

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. Are you asking for a [css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System) decryption implementation in c# or are you asking how to decrypt files that are encrypted using some other form and the file just happens to be on a DVD? Also what is your final goal, there may be better tools to suit your needs if you describe your final goal instead of just one step.

Comment: He wants to decrypt on the fly, so he can play back encrypted media without first copying to disc and decrypting if i understand him correctly. without knowing anything about the media type or encryption this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Are you talking about DVD video protected by CSS or something else? For playing DVDs, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873698/dvd-playback-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options, from hardest to easiest (both hard anyway)

1. You can implement a codec to decode video file. Without a proper codec even a uncompressed avi file seems like encrypted to Media Player. All decryption is in codec.
2. You can implement a Frame Server like VirtualDub did. In this case you will need to implement a codec too. Decryption is delegated to Frame Server application. In virtualDub case, codec was just a man-in-middle.
3. You can implement a streaming web server like uTorrent did. This is the easiest, you just need to implement HttpServer, which I believe is not so hard in C#, to decrypt and stream data. Tricky part is, you may need to keep an index of encrypted blocks to enable forwarding.